# Why does the following Code throw a NullReferenceException?

Tags: c#, initialization, nullreferenceexception

I know that most cases of a NullReferenceException are caused of missing initialization. But I initializated MTemp and FTemp.

What I'm missing?

---

Important code inside the class "Foo":

```
class Team
{
    public List<Fahrer> TeamFahrer { get; set; }

    public void Bar(string salad, string hotdog, string brokkoli)
    {
        Motorrad MTemp = new Motorrad(brokkoli);
        Fahrer FTemp = new Fahrer(salad, hotdog, MTemp);
        TeamFahrer.Add(FTemp);
    }
}
```

---

Important code inside Motorrad:

```
class Motorrad
{
    public Motorrad(string marke)
    {
        Marke = marke;
    }

    public string Marke { get; set; }
}
```

---

Important Code inside Fahrer:

```
class Fahrer
{
    public Fahrer(string salad, string hotdog, Motorrad moped)
    {
        Vorname = salad;
        Nachname = hotdog;
        MotorradDesFahrers = moped;
    }

    public string Vorname { get; set; }
    public string Nachname { get; set; }
    public Motorrad MotorradDesFahrers { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Do you initialize `TeamFahrer`?

Comment: You haven't initialized TeamFahrer. Before you call "Add", you need to call TeamFahrer = new List<Fahrer>();

Comment: You are missing information about exception AND what of steps you've taken to debug after reading the "How to fix NRE" question already proposed as duplicate. (I think this is just poorly researched question - so not voting to close yet and just downvoting)

Comment: Thanks! I searched the whole time at the wrong end!

Answer (score 0):

```
class Team
{
   public List<Fahrer> TeamFahrer { get; set; }
   public Team()
   { 
     TeamFahrer  = new List<Fahrer>();
   }
}
```

Initialize `TeamFahrer` in the constructor of your class.

Comment: Thank you! I searched the whole time at the wrong end!

Comment: @AlexHeld Please mark answered if resolved your query. It saves other developers time to take a look into other unanswered questions.